# Find comments but not summaries in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

So, I'd like to find all commented out code in my codebase in order to delete them.

I do not want search and replace because some of the comments are not code, but helpful texts.

1. I want commented out code starting with // (not /*) - those are much easier to find.
2. Also I do not want the search to include documentation (which all starts with ///)
3. Futhermore, there is an autogenerated comment, which I dont want in the search result, like: // blah

This is to high level regex for me :-)

Comment: Would be easier to write a script, say in `Python` that will crawl over all the file, rather then get into complicated RegEx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[`\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/|(?<!\/)\/{2}(?!\/|\s*blah).*|$`](https://regex101.com/r/KqOo7Z/3)

This will:

- Match blocks of commented code `/* ... */`  (even though you've mentioned " *not to match /* - those are much easier to find* "). If you don't want this simply remove `\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/` from the regex above.
- Match `//` but not match `///` nor `// blah`. That is: `(?<!\/)\/{2}(?!\/|\s*blah).*`

Comment: This is weird. It works in the Online Regex Tester, but when I do it in visual studio, it finds all sorts of matches:

Find all "\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/|(?<!\/)\/{2}(?!\/|\s*blah).*|$", Regular expressions, Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, "*.cs"
  C:\Repositories\...\App.xaml.cs(2):using System;
  C:\Repositories\...\App.xaml.cs(3):using System.Globalization;
  C:\Repositories\...\App.xaml.cs(4):using System.Windows;
  ...